# How To Attach File On Axios Post Request In Vue

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, axios

Hello I am trying to attach file for `axios.post` however when I do a console.log() the `formData` is empty so here is what I am working with.

On my vue form

```
<form @submit.prevent="uploadTodos">
  <div>
   <input type="file" v-on:change="selectedFile($event)">
   <label>Choose file</label>
  </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the data object

```
data() {
     return {
         file: null,
      }
}
```

and method I have for the `selectedFile` on change event

```
selectedFile(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0]
    },
```

and here is the submit event method

```
 uploadTodos() {
      let formData = new FormData
      formData.append('file', this.file) 
      this.$store.dispatch('uploadTodos', formData)
    }
```

and here is the store method being dispatch

```
uploadTodos(context, file) {
      console.log(file)
      axios.post('/import', file,{ headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        context.commit('importTodos', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data)
      })
    }
```

and when I console.log(file) I get the `formData` I created in the uploadTodos() method however it is empty, So I am trying to figure out why it is empty?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't `log` the form data directly. Instead, you want to loop over the formdata. `for(let pair of formData.entries())`, and `pair[0]` is the key and `pair[1]` is the contents.

Comment: okay so after `console.log()` the `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` I am showing this in the console. `file, [object File]` which is what I have after using `formData.append('file', this.file)` so I guess my question is still why is it empty? Im sure it should be my actual file data correct?